# Android junit: Method scheme in android.net.Uri&Builder Not Mocked

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

I'm trying to learn how to do unit tests in Android and I'm stuck with this particular issue. I searched for previous SO posts but none are relevant to this error. I'm getting this exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Method scheme in android.net.Uri$Builder not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.

Why is it saying that method "scheme" of Uri.Builder needs to be mocked? Thanks!

**MovieDBAPITest.java**

```
package com.karljamoralin.popularmovies;

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class MovieDBAPITest {

    MovieDBAPI movieDBAPI = new MovieDBAPI();

    @Test
    public void URLValidator() {
        assertEquals("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=test&language=en-US",
                movieDBAPI.buildUri("top_rated").toString());
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals("a", movieDBAPI.test());
    }

}
```

**MovieDBAPI.java**

```
package com.karljamoralin.popularmovies;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class MovieDBAPI extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        Uri uri = buildUri(params[0]);

        Log.v(TAG, uri.toString());

        //Connect to URL

        //Get string input

        //Parse string input

        //Return M

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

    Uri buildUri(String mode) {

        final String SCHEME = "https";
        final String AUTHORITY = "api.themoviedb.org";
        final String PATH1 = "3";
        final String PATH2 = "movie";
        final String API_KEY = "movie";
        final String LANGUAGE = "language";

        Uri.Builder uriBuilder = new Uri.Builder();
        uriBuilder.scheme(SCHEME);
        uriBuilder.authority(AUTHORITY);
        uriBuilder.appendPath(PATH1);
        uriBuilder.appendPath(PATH2);
        uriBuilder.appendPath(mode);
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter(API_KEY, "test");
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter(LANGUAGE, "en-US");

        return uriBuilder.build();

    }

    String test() {
        return "a";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, that kind a test sucks with Android SDK.
The `Uri` class is not implemented in the dev jar.

My advise would be to make wrapper classes for those situations and use those wrappers in your tests. Other possibilities are to use [Robolectric](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric) or [Android Instrumentation Tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html).

Comment: How would you use Robolectric for **Uri.Builder**?

Comment: This is from long ago, I know things have changed on everything involved here, but I am not dealing with this very often right now. What I think I had in mind is that Roboletric had its own mock, but I don't recall if that is/was true to be honest.